# Regex to find loose PHP comparisons which are always safe to turn into strict comparisons

Tags: php, regex, refactoring, comparison-operators

I'm refactoring a big and old application with a lot of loose comparisons (`X == $var`) and want to implement strict comparisons wherever possible (`X === $var`). To do this, to safe time, I want to find all / as many as possible cases in which the strict comparison can be safely implemented without checking the possible values and understanding code.

Examples:

`"foobar" == $var` can always be turned into `"foobar" === $var`.

`"true" == $var` can not safely be turned into `"true" === $var`, since `"true" == true` is **true**, but `"true" === true` is **false**.

Ideally, there is a regex or library which finds all cases in one go, for all possible types and all possible comparison operators.

Second best option: A rule based list of cases in which the blind refactoring is not possible.

Such a list / regex would be super helpful for anyone doing a large refactoring of code. There are many lists out there, but I foud none which serves exactly this purpose.

Comment: The problem I can see is that you need to understand the context and the possible values of each comparison at run time.  So just looking for string patterns just find instances of particular strings.  So `"true" === $var`, how do you know what `$var` contains unless you run the code?

Comment: There are cases in which knowing the code is necessary and cases in which it is not necessary. Your comment concerns the former situation. This is true. In these cases, understanding context is inevitable to safely refactor. However, I'm focussing on the second case, where it is possible to ignore the context, see the first example in the original question.